# jQuery Horizontal scroll adding extra image not displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery [Horizontal scroll plugi](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/)n for scroll [Demo](http://www.tonylea.com/go/examples/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/).

When i add extra images to the li it won't display the added images. anyone have idea?

```
<ul id="horiz_container_outer">
        <li id="horiz_container_inner">
            <ul id="horiz_container">
                <li><img src="images/toystory.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="Toy Story" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/up.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="UP" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/ratatouille.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="Ratatouille" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/findingnemo.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="Finding Nemo" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/cars.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="Cars" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/monstersinc.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="Monsters Inc" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/bugslife.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="A Bugs Life" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/incredibles.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="The Incredibles" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/bugslife.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="A Bugs Life" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/incredibles.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="The Incredibles" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/bugslife.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="A Bugs Life" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/toystory.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="The Incredibles" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/bugslife.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="A Bugs Life" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/toystory.png" width="500px" height="300px" alt="The Incredibles" /></li>
            </ul>
        </li>       
</ul>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#horiz_container_outer').horizontalScroll();

});
```

Comment: can you show the code on jsfiddle.com...??? bcox i can't play with it's CSS here

Comment: please download the files from http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/.

Comment: it's done..!!! Can you tell me how much pictures youwant to add...???

Comment: Please just add the li tags and then look out the page the recently added li is not displaying but it is in dom

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i found is by adjusting the css.
In its root folder there is a CSS fiel name **jquery.horizontal.scroll.css**

I changed it like below and now i have 14 pictures currently showing:

```
#horiz_container
{
    width:7064px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

all i played with **width** and **margin-left** attributes.

Go to ur **.php** file and add 14 images and change CSS of id **#horiz_container** like i have mentioned.

Comment: but the width 7064 is calculated through coding only  not through css